# Assign values to the tensors in keras while defining a new loss function

Tags: keras, tensor, loss

I am trying to define a loss function in Keras

```python
def rmseApprox(y_true, y_pred):
    dum = y_pred
    dum[y_pred>=0]=1.1
    dum[y_pred<0]=1

    return k.abs(K.mean(y_true - dum*y_pred), axis=-1)
```

which increase the positive values by a factor of 1.1 and the compare it with the true values. I got the following error:

```py
TypeError: 'Tensor' object does not support item assignment
```

Answer (score 0):

The loss function is a tensor and part of the computational graph. It therefore must be defined using the [keras backend](https://keras.io/backend/), and doesn't behave like a "regular" numpy array.

This example should work for you:

```
def rmseApprox(y_true, y_pred):
    y_pred_corrected = y_pred*(1.05 + K.sign(y_pred)*0.05)
    return K.abs(K.mean(y_true - y_pred_corrected, axis=-1))
```

Please note that in the above code, the weight for the case `y_pred==0` will be `1.05`.

Comment: Thank you so much! It is working nice but I need to modify it a bit to have a better regression results.